# How to launch another program from within erlang code

Tags: erlang

I downloaded the program ImageMagik (www.imagemagick.org/). It can be executed from command line and takes command-line arguments which is perfect for me. How do I execute the program from within a module in Erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either os:cmd call

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1

or use port

open port http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_port.html

Answer (score 1):

Use emagick, https://github.com/kivra/emagick

which already has the necessary bindings ready.